# terraform - create instances on list of strings

Tags: terraform

```
resource "aws_instance" "jenkins_worker_inst" {
  for_each = toset(["peter", "nelson", "chris"])

  provider                    = aws.region_worker
  ami                         = data.aws_ssm_parameter.worker-linuxAmi.value
  instance_type               = var.instance-type
  key_name                    = aws_key_pair.worker_key_pair.key_name
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.jenkins_worker_sg.id]
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.worker_subnet_1.id
  tags = {
    Name = each.key
  }
  depends_on = [aws_main_route_table_association.set-worker-default-rt-assoc, aws_instance.jenkins_master_inst]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
  #aws --debug --profile ${var.profile} ec2 wait instance-status-ok   --region ${var.region_master} --instance-ids "${self.id}" ansible-playbook  --verbose --extra-vars 'passed_in_hosts=tag_Name_${self.tags.Name}'     ansible_templates/jenkins-worker-sample.yml
 EOF
  }
}
```

I am told that the for_each here should be able to make 3 instances, but it is making 1.
i have tried it with terraform 0.12 and 1.0.0.   I really need a way to make the number of instances based on list of something

Comment: I feel dumb.  My IDE was editing one set of terraform.  my terminal was in a different path running Terraform from a different project that had a an identical instance block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are essentially 2 ways to accomplish what you are trying to do. One way is with [the for_each meta-argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html), which is what you attempted. The other way is by using [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html), which would look something this.

```
locals {
  instance_names = ["peter", "nelson", "chris"]
}

resource "aws_instance" "jenkins_worker_inst" {
  count = length(instance_names)

  provider                    = aws.region_worker
  ami                         = data.aws_ssm_parameter.worker-linuxAmi.value
  instance_type               = var.instance-type
  key_name                    = aws_key_pair.worker_key_pair.key_name
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.jenkins_worker_sg.id]
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.worker_subnet_1.id
  tags = {
    Name = element(local.instance_names, count.index)
  }
  depends_on = [aws_main_route_table_association.set-worker-default-rt-assoc, aws_instance.jenkins_master_inst]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
  #aws --debug --profile ${var.profile} ec2 wait instance-status-ok   --region ${var.region_master} --instance-ids "${self.id}" ansible-playbook  --verbose --extra-vars 'passed_in_hosts=tag_Name_${self.tags.Name}'     ansible_templates/jenkins-worker-sample.yml
 EOF
  }
}
```

The for_each meta-argument should work for Terraform v0.12.6+. If you tried using it in a version of Terraform prior to v0.12.6, then for_each would not yet be supported; you would only have count as an option.

You also stated that you tried it with Terraform v1.0+, which does support for_each. Without additional information (plan?), I can't tell you why that didn't work. However, I can say that sometimes Terraform does wonkey stuff and in the past, there have been breaking changes introduced in minor and patch versions, sometimes without announcement.

Finally, [This Medium post](https://medium.com/@business_99069/terraform-count-vs-for-each-b7ada2c0b186) does a pretty decent job of explaining the differences between count and for_each. But for your example, either should work just fine.